# Can I get member field via foreach or other loop construct?

Tags: c#, collections

It is my global variable. The class has 1000 members.

```
internal class Global
{

    internal static int a1;
    internal static int a2;
    internal static int a3;
    ...
    ...
    internal static int a1000;   
}
```

When btn1 is pressed, I want to save its value to a file like below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    foreach( value in member )
    {
        //put value to file         
    }    
}
```

How can I access its member via foreach or other loop construct?

Comment: You probably want to use an array for this.

Comment: What about enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be better to have array of `int` and loop the `int` array instead of `Global`,

```
internal class Global
{
    internal static int [] Arr;
}


foreach(int value in Globalmember.Arr)
{
    //put value to file         
}
```

Although you can use get the members of a class using [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx), see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340438/get-value-of-static-field). The following examples shows how you can get the properties using [System.Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
Type type = typeof(TestGlobal);
FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static); 
foreach (var field in fields) 
{
    if(field.Name.StartsWith("a"))
        Debug.WriteLine(field.Name);
}
```

**Note** You should name the attributes in a way that they could be searched in fields collection uniquely. For example `a` could be present in many other attributes you do not want, but `aaa` is less likely to be present in other attributes.